# How to view AWS Billing cost for resources created by an IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

### In brief

We need to view AWS cost for resources created by a specific IAM user via `aws:createdBy` tag.

### In full

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=how+to+view+AWS+Billing+cost+for+an+IAM+user&oq=how+to+view+AWS+Billing+cost+for+an+IAM+user&aqs=chrome..69i57.11095j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is not helpful - it gives me one idea to use [Consolidated Billing for Organizations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html) to have the view of cost-by-user billing but that requires to create separate AWS users, which again requires credit card.

Another solution I found is that we can view AWS cost by [tag grouping via Cost Explorer report](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html) though we cannot find the mentioned tag `createdBy` as stated in [that AWS guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html)?

The ideal solution should let us create as many IAM users as the number of projects may grow i.e. one IAM user per project; and then, give us the report of AWS cost for each of those users.

So, how can we get to it?

[image]

Comment: How would costs be meaningfully associated with an IAM user?  If user uploaded an object to S3, would that user be associated with the object's ongoing monthly storage cost? If a user launched an EC2 instance, would the user be associated with the monthly instance hours?  It isn't clear what actual problem you are trying to solve, since the definintion of terms -- cost for a specific user (the consequences of that user's actions) -- seems difficult to conceptualize in any generally meaningful way.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have updated my OP to clarify the point of using `aws:createdBy` tag

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Your question can be answered by the mentioned guide from AWS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

Answer (score 5):

Costs are **not** incurred by IAM Users. The AWS Account owning the resource incurs the charge.

When an IAM User makes a request to AWS, their credentials are verified to ensure that they are the authorized person and their permissions are checked to confirm that they have permission to perform the operation. However, there is no further relationship between the person making the request and the resource that is created.

The closest connection is the audit log created by AWS CloudTrail that can show which user made each request. But this is not related to billing information.

If you wish to track costs, you should **associate tags with resources**. These tags could be based on department, cost center, person, etc. You can then configure your Detailed Billing Report to provide cost breakdowns by tag.

Comment: I have update my OP to clarify the point of using `aws:createdBy` tag which guided by official AWS site at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

Comment: And yes, as you pointed out, we can track the cost using associated tags which is `createdBy` here and not found in Billing console at the moment.

Comment: [AWS-Generated Cost Allocation Tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/aws-tags.html) says: "The AWS-generated tag is available only in the Billing and Cost Management console and reports, and doesn't appear anywhere else in the AWS console, including the AWS Tag Editor."

Comment: Sorry but what is AWS Tag Editor here?

Comment: From [Working with Tag Editor](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/tag-editor.html): "On the navigation bar, choose Resource Groups, and then choose Tag Editor."

Comment: Seem like we are leaded by hou far away from the OP - view cost of AWS resources that created by an IAM user. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more concise solution systematically using your own tags by setting up Lambda, CloudWatch, CloudTrail, and SSM to achieve it.
Here are some references:

1. [Automatically tag new AWS resources based on identity or role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/auto-tag-aws-resources/)
2. [GitHub - resource auto tag](https://github.com/aws-samples/resource-auto-tagger)