# AWS Control IAM user spending

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do I control IAM user spending?

If my IAM user A spends $5k a month, I should have the option to throttle or block his EC2 usage, but still allow access to S3.

Comment: [how-to-view-aws-billing-cost-for-resources-created-by-an-iam-user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498517/2246345). In crux you have to use tags to groups the resources in the billing.

Comment: aws:CreatedBy works to some extent. But for example, there is thouosands of dollars assigned to an "AssumedRole" user each month, and I have no idea who assumed role is

Comment: you can still find out who assumed the role from cloudtrail [Logging IAM and AWS STS API requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cloudtrail-integration.html#cloudtrail-integration_apis)